# How is concept of Lorentz local field considered in Heisenberg model?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, spin-models

The quantum Hamiltonian of Heisenberg model is usually given in the form:
$$\textit{H}_{heisenberg}=-\sum_{i,j}J_{ij}\vec{S}_{i}\cdot\vec{S}_{j}-g\mu_{B}\vec{H}\cdot\sum_{i}\vec{S}_{i}$$
such that first term corresponds to exchange interaction between spin, and second term corresponds to interaction of spin with external magnetic field.

I am confused about the second term, because it seems like effects from neighboring atom must be included in field H. Since famous ferromagnetic material, Fe, Ni, and Co, has cubic symmetry in crystal structure, concept of Lorentz local field will apply well. So, I wonder if term $\vec{H}$ should be replaced into  $\vec{H}_{loc}=\vec{H}_{ext}+\frac{4\pi}{3}\vec{M}$ or something. Since typical saturation magnetization of these materials are order of $1000G$, which is comparable to usual experimental value of $\vec{H}_{ext}$, I think this contribution proportional to $\vec{M}$ cannot be neglected.

What is the proper treatment for this problem? Is the contribution of demagentizing field just included in exchange constant $J_{ij}$ and omitted, since correction $\vec{M}\cdot\vec{S}_{i}\approx\frac{g\mu_{B}}{V}\langle\sum_{j}\vec{S}_{j}\rangle\cdot\vec{S}_{i}$ corresponds to spin-spin interaction? If not, then is it averaged to zero due to random orientation of domain structure?

Comment: The second term should come from an external field. The effect from neighboring atoms are contained in the first term.